# js window.location.reload() очень долго перезагружает страницу

Tags: jquery, laravel-5.6

Есть форма и в ней datatable. Отправляю форму на сервер методом POST с помощью ajax. После получения ответа от сервера я хочу полностью перезагрузить страницу. Все хорошо работает пока записей в таблице мало, но если записей более 500-та штук, то клик по кнопке срабатывает с опозданием (примерно через 6-8 секунд, это видно по прелоадеру, который запускается при клике по кнопке "сохранить"), а страница очень долго перезагружается (минимальное время 3 минуты, максимальное 5 минут). Данные на сервер отсылаются примерно 1-3 секунды (при большом кол-ве записей), а  ответ от сервера приходит за пол секунды. Подскажите как можно исправить.

jQuery script

```
$('#editLessonButton').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#overlay').fadeIn();
    var $form = $('.DlsLessonForm');
    var postData = $form.serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{csrf_token()}}'},
        url: "{{url('admin/lessons/AjaxEditLesson')}}",
        method: 'POST',
        data: postData,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == 'edit_ok'){
                window.location.reload(true);
            }
            $('#overlay').fadeOut();
        }
     });
});
```

Comment: Приведите воспроизводимый пример. И что-то мне подсказывает, что ларка тут не причём.

Comment: Попробуйте не .reload() а location.href на текущую локацию. Тогда будет не перезагрузка текущей страницы, а якобы переход на текущую страницу. Должно помочь. 
`window.location.href = window.location.href;`

Comment: @adudnik.ru  Пробывал так, результат тотже. Вечером постараюсь кинуть воспроизводимый пример

Comment: Сделайте отдельную страницу-заглушку об успешном добавлении данных или редирект на уровень вверх. Сейчас вспимнил что при перезагрузке страницы форма может повторно отправляться. Видимо в этом дело.

Comment: Подробнее об этой проблеме: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: @adudnik.ru забыл сказать, что без аякса (просто клик по кнопке) reload отрабатывает быстро как надо, а вот уже в аяксе долго (то есть ответ edit_ok приходит за пол секунды и страница уходит в вечный перезагруз.). Если в ларе в контроллере пишу return back() или redirect, то страница обновляется почти мгновенно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем отключил в Larvel в env дебаг режим (APP_DEBUG=false) и все заработало как надо. Видимо как-то связано с laravel debugbar.